# Configuring RBS for SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, remote-blob-storage

I setup RBS per MSDN article. It's all working. I would like to RBS everything regardless of file size. I think by default it only RBS files that are >=100kb.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This is configured via SharePoint per content database (RBS is per content database).

```
$contentdb = Get-SPContentDatabase –WebApplication http://yourweburl
$rbs = $coontentdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbs.MinimumBlobStorageSize = <size in bytes>
```